# Does it looks like a bandpass matching network?

Tags: rf, radio, impedance-matching, receiver, band-pass

I am trying to understand this receiver and figure out what does this L-C network is.

[image]

I read about matching networks and found this example, I am curious if it is the same thing. ***is it?***

[image]

In the datasheet of [SYN531R](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1811141751_Synoxo-SYN531R_C77785.pdf) it says
`two components for the matching network, and two components for the pre-selector band pass filter`, what is the
`matching network` made of (*C2, L2?*) and what is the `pre-selector band pass filter` made of (*C1, L1?*) ?

Comment: You need to learn how to simulate this

Comment: To full understand it, you need the antenna impedance and consider, s11 for ESD and stray transmit power suppression out of band then s21 for BPF. So this is a compromise.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Sorry, I am not well versed in analog/radio, but I will look into how to simulate this, I was hoping to have the right answer before start making prototypes and testing ... I brought some 20 of these syn531 and F115 to play with radio communications in a digital board (stm8s105), the final Idea is to make these boards talk to each other using manchester encoding and cheap radio modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L1 (27 nH) and C1 (5 pF) form a band pass filter whose resonant frequency is: -

$$\dfrac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{LC}} = \text{433.16 MHz}$$

This is near enough to 433.92 MHz not to get in a pickle over because it's a fairly low Q filter due to the impedance of the antenna assumed to be around 50 ohms: -

[image]

Picture taken from [this on-line analyser](http://stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RCL%20BPF/RCL%20BPF.html).

C2 and L2 form a high pass filter like this: -

[image]

Picture from [this analyser](http://stades.co.uk/RLC%20filters/RCL%20HPF/RCL%20HPF.html).

I've chosen R (in this example) to reflect the 50 ohms output impedance of the previous band-pass stage.

C2 and L2 are an impedance matching stage and, for it to be effective necessitates that the antenna pin on the SYN531 has an input impedance of several hundred ohms but unfortunately, the data sheet is sadly lacking in this respect so you have to take their word for it.

Anyway, the impedance transformer works like this: -

[image]

This means that: -

$$R_L = \dfrac{L}{R_{IN}\cdot C}= \text{178 ohms}$$

I expect that the input impedance of the SY531 is a bit more than this and, if we use the other equation we find that "F" is 538 MHz and pretty much where the peak is in the 2nd simulation graph. So, I expect the input impedance of the SY531 will be around 200 to 300 ohms, hence it uses an impedance matching circuit.

Comment: Nice. Regarding impedance match end...Assuming \$R_L\$ is a pure resistance higher than 50 ohms is a good first-approach. Similar chips often have a small capacitance in parallel with \$R_L\$. When combined with the external \$L\$, match occurs at a lower frequency, and at a higher impedance...closer to Andy's estimate of a few hundred ohms.

Answer (score 0):

my sim (with 500 5-0-0 ohm Rsource)  shows peaks at 290 MHz and 690 MHz, and -10 dB sag between, because of the high_Quality (low losses)

with 100 ohm, I see -3dB at 300 MHz and +6 dB at 600MHz

with 50 Ohm source, -3dB at 300 MHz, +7db (yes, a mild stepup, yet a great boost to noise figure) at 500MHz, and then -3dB at 1,200MHz

I'd expect this circuit to bypass most ESD energy to ground through the first inductor.

I'd expect a peak somewhat higher in frequency (because of the 2 caps in series), with again the higher frequency energy being attenuated once past the resonance.